# Updating NuGet package causes Source Control error because content files are not overwritten

Tags: version-control, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

Quite often when installing some of the js* library packages nuget copies js files to Scripts directory of the web project and puts these files under source control.
Yet while updating the package instead of just rewriting the files nuget first removes them and then copies new versions. Because of that TFS shows the error about conflicting state: Files are scheduled for removal but present locally.

Can we somehow change this behavior or is it completely defined by the author of the package?

Comment: How do you update the packages? With the Update-Package command?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT Via GUI, Update package. It is the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

No, this behavior is not defined by the package author.

And since NuGet 2.5, it is allowed to overwrite content files that already exist. Check: https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.5

You need to use the Update-Package command to update NuGet packages.